# The template deployment failed with error when creating azure spot vm machine

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I'm new to azure & trying to deploying a Spot Virtual Machine with windows server 2019 gen2. When I try to create virtual machine I got this error

"The template deployment failed with error: 'The resource with id: '/subscriptions/6b3845e9-2c4e-44c6-baaf-5efb515334c2/resourceGroups/cloud-vcenter/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/EXsi' failed validation with message: 'The requested size for resource '/subscriptions/6b3845e9-2c4e-44c6-baaf-5efb515334c2/resourceGroups/cloud-vcenter/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/EXsi' is currently not available in location 'eastus' zones '' for subscription '6b3845e9-2c4e-44c6-baaf-5efb515334c2'. Please try another size or deploy to a different location or zones. See https://aka.ms/azureskunotavailable for details.'.'. (Code: InvalidTemplateDeployment)"

How can I solve this error? My account belong to "Azure for Students" subscription.

Comment: Please share the code you are using.

Comment: what is the vm_size  you are using?

Answer (score 0):

> "The template deployment failed with error: 'The resource with id: '/subscriptions/6b3845e9-2c4e-44c6-baaf-5efb515334c2/resourceGroups/cloud vcenter/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/EXsi'
> failed validation with message: 'The requested size for resource '/subscriptions/6b3845e9-2c4e-44c6-baaf-5efb515334c2/resourceGroups/cloudvcenter/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/EXsi' is currently not available in location 'eastus' zones '' for subscription '6b3845e9-2c4e-44c6-baaf-5efb515334c2'. Please try another size or deploy to a different location or zones. Seehttps://aka.ms/azureskunotavailable for details.'.'. (Code: InvalidTemplateDeployment)"

This error causes due to

- The VM size isn't available for a location or zone.
- ***SKUNotAvailable***-There is not enough Azure Spot Virtual Machine capacity in this location to create your VM or scale set instance.

If SKU is not available send an SKU request to Azure Support if an SKU is not offered for your subscription in a region or zone .

You check the available resources in selected region by using command **Get-AzureRmComputeResourceSku** then proceed to launch VM.

```
Get-AzureRmComputeResourceSku | where {$_.Locations -icontains "eastus"}
```

***Output:***

[image]

If the got actually available for your subscription\location combination you should use:

```
Get-AzVMSize -Location %location%
```

***Output:***
[image]

They also has some [limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/spot-vms#limitations) in VM sizes are not supported for Azure Spot Virtual Machines

***Reference:***
[Error codes for Azure Spot Virtual Machines and scale sets instances - Azure Virtual Machines | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/error-codes-spot)